# image/icon use a relative path

Tags: java, eclipse, relative-path

I don't really get how to properly use a relative path in Eclipse. I created a res folder next to the src folder with a image folder in it.

This is my current code:

```
public class ToolbarView extends JToolBar {
    JButton addButton = new JButton("\\images\\button.png");
```

Comment: remove \\ infront of `images`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
JButton addButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images\button.png")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an icon using `getClass().getResource(...)` like this :

```
 Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/button.png"));
 JButton b = new JButton(icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Based on the forum](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/344961-imageicon-nullpointerexception/) instead of writing down **/res/image.png** you just have to write **/image.png** .It worked for me. (The image was in the src/main/resources folder by the way)

Comment: The "Based on the Forum" link, it directed me to an online gambling website.

Answer (score 0):

you could write it like this instead.

```
JButton addButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/button.png"));
```